# WooCommerce - Refresh item quantity when item is added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When the user selects their quantity and clicks the add to cart button, the item is added to the cart with the correct quantity. However, if the user clicks add to cart again for the same item but with a different quantity, then that will be added to the original quantity.

What I want to happen is the original item quantity to be removed and updated with the new item quantity.

How would this be possible?

Comment: you will need to script the 'remove from cart' for the product if it already exists and then 'add to cart'

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand?

Comment: what you need is a piece of code to check if the product already exists in cart, if it does, delete the product from the cart and add the new info

Comment: Yes, that is what I need help with.

Comment: This is not a place to request help with coding. We can help you if you tried something and the code does not work. all the best!

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I have been trying for several hours but haven't been able to solve it. I've edited my original post to show what I've been attempting to use.

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html. check get_cart_item,  remove_cart_item & add_to_cart.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from Lucky Chingi I managed to make it work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart_before' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before( $cart_item_data ) {
$cart = WC()->instance()->cart;
$id = $_POST['product_id'];
$cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id($id);
$cart_item_id = $cart->find_product_in_cart($cart_id);

if($cart_item_id){
$cart->set_quantity($cart_item_id,0);
}
return true;
}
```